# How do use a $or operator for one property and then not use it for another in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following query and I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

```
Offer.findOne({
    $or: [
        { title: { $regex : new RegExp(guideJoin, 'i') } },
        { _id: title },
    ],
    offerActive: true
})
```

I want to be able to search the database for an offer that matches for either the title value or the _id value, but the offerActive value also needs to be set to true. This will return results when the _id is provided, but not if it has to match the offer by 'title'. Does anyone know why this is? This query can identity the offers by title if I remove the $or and '_id' elements of this query so I know it works.

**Edit**
I removed the 'offerActive: true' line and it can still only identify offers by their _id.

Answer (score 0):

```
Offer.findOne({$and:[
{
    $or: [
        { title: { $regex : guideJoin, $options:'i'} },
        { _id: title },
    ],
}
,{offerActive: true}
]}
)
```

Comment: this doesn't work either, the issue is within the $or operator, I tried without regex and it still doesn't work